# Connecting MySQL Workbench database to a Java application in NetBeans

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect a MySQL database in my Java application in NetBeans, which currently only has 1 entry for username and password. Whenever I execute the SQL statement in the MySQL Workbench the correct information is being pulled back.

I have this as my current code in NetBeans to connect the database to the login page I have created:

```
String userName = inputUsernameTextFrontPage.getText();
    String password = inputPasswordTextFrontPage.getText();
    
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql","root","Password23");
        String sql = "SELECT username,password FROM adminlogin WHERE username =? AND password =? AND ID =?";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, userName);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
        preparedStatement.setLong  (3, 1);
        ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        
        if(result.next()){
            setVisible(false);
            new adminLogin().setVisible(true);
        }
        else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Incorrect Login Details");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  e.getStackTrace());        
    }
```

Sorry, I am new to this, can anyone see any issues with this as the database is connected successfully in NetBeans. Every time I run the program, it just jumps straight to the catch part and brings back "Connection Error".

Any help would be much appreciated. Let me know if you need any further information as I am not sure if that makes sense to others.

The error message I am getting when adding in the e.getStackTrace() is
[error message when using e.getStackTrace()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHTdw.png)

Comment: can you show the error log? Add a logging statement (such as e.printStackTrace()) in the catch block

Comment: There are two problems here that I can see: firstly, you're not leaving spaces at the ends of lines so the query you send to the database is `SELECT username, passwordFROM test.adminloginWHERE ...`.   Spot the problem?  Secondly, **please** use prepared statements: don't just concatenate values into SQL strings.

Comment: Fix the errors Luke indicated, and if the problem still occurs, please update your code and post the full exception stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel hi, I have updated my code on this post, I'm now not sure where there are any errors

Comment: Please include the exception stacktrace (use logging, or `e.printStackTrace()`). Or at minimum change your message dialog to show something like `"Connection Error: " + e`, so you know what the actual problem is.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel i have updated the code in the post and included an image of the errors that are coming up

Comment: That is in the middle of the stacktrace, and doesn't contain the important parts, like the exception message and any causes.

Answer (score 0):

As others already pointed out there are several issues in your code.
First **check your sql connector version if it's version 5 then avoid using** **.cj** prefix inside the `classForName()`.Change it as  `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

Then please use PreparedStatements instead of createStatements to the queries which have variable parameters to get passed.

Additional: Please use camel case while naming the variables in Java.Ex:username must be userName

**Sample solution after using PreparedStatement instead of createStatement**.

```
String username = inputUsernameTextFrontPage.getText();
String password = inputPasswordTextFrontPage.getText();
```

```
String sql = "SELECT username,password FROM adminlogin WHERE username =? AND password =? AND ID =?";

PreparedStatement preparedStatement =
        connection.prepareStatement(sql);

preparedStatement.setString(1, username);
preparedStatement.setString(2, password);
preparedStatement.setLong  (3, 1);

ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I am still getting the error when I run the program and type in the admin username and password where it jumps straight to the catch part of the code and just brings up the 'Connection Error' line i have in my code. I have added in your suggestions to use prepared statement instead of create statement.

Comment: @ashleigh14 did you check your mysql connector version?

Comment: Yes its was version 5 like you said so I went and removed the .cj part like you suggested. I have updated my code on this post.

Comment: @ashleigh14 Please change your code like below ,and re post the error you are getting in the console log. code:```catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println( e.getStackTrace());    //add this line to your above catch block
    }```     Please notify me by a comment after updating the post.

Comment: I have updated the post with an image I have included of the error message I am receiving when typing in the getStackTrace()